# Perl: Regex matching is unsuccessful

Tags: regex, perl

I've tried several different variations of regex, but I still cannot get `$found` to return results. I've tested these regex on regexterster.com which shows a positive match against the examples in `@domains`.

I suspect I'm making a very noobish mistake here:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @domains = ('apples.eat-healthy.com', 'seeds.for-parrots.co.nz', 'spam.sender.info');

my $domain_patterns = qr/
    [A-Z0-9-]+\.[A-Z0-9]{3}$|
    [A-Z0-9-]+\.[A-Z0-9]{2}\.[A-Z0-9]{2}$|
    [A-Z0-9-]+\.[A-Z0-9]{4}$
    /x;

foreach my $domain (@domains) {
    if (my ($found) = $domain =~ m/($domain_patterns)/i) {
        print "Found: $found\n";
    }
}
```

Could someone please point out what I'm doing incorrectly?

Comment: [Domain::PublicSuffix](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Domain::PublicSuffix) might be of use to you.

Comment: I find it interesting that regextester.com has the `i`, `g`, `m`, and `s` flags (case-insensitive, global, multiline, and newlines count as whitespace) set on by default, which isn't the case for any language that I know of, and undoubtedly contributed to OP's confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `/i` needs to be on the `qr//`.

I think this can best be explained through example:

```
my $re1 = qr/B/i;
my $re2 = qr/C/;

/A$re1$re2/i

# ABC   matches
# aBC   matches (Because of /i on /A/i)
# AbC   matches (Because of /i on qr/B/i)
# ABc   doesn't match (C must be uppercase because of lack of /i on qr/C/)
```

Comment: Yes, I meant that `i` should be added. `x` should not be removed.

Comment: When checking with `use re 'debug'` these regexes seem to be doing quite a lot of backtracking. In other words: They seem very inefficient.

Comment: @TLP, That should be a comment to the OP. A lot of the backtracking is due to the lack of a leading anchor.

Comment: @ikegami I know, but I wanted your input on it, since I recall that you have knowledge on the subject.

Comment: @TLP Is there a way I can improve my regex? I couldn't see a way to add a leading anchor, since I'm not sure what the beginning characters might be.

Answer (score 3):

Either add the case insensitive modifier or change your expression to:

```
[A-Za-z0-9\-]+\.[A-Za-z0-9]{3}$|
[A-Za-z0-9\-]+\.[A-Za-z0-9]{2}\.[A-Za-z0-9]{2}$|
[A-Za-z0-9\-]+\.[A-Za-z0-9]{4}$
```